# Why does \x3C make JS/Html flip out?

Tags: javascript, html

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/2vx6T/

```
$('#c').html('<a href=#>Z\x3CX</a>');
alert($('#c').html());
```

Gets me

```
<a href="#">Z<x< a=""></x<></a>
```

Why? Where are all the `<`, `=` and `"` coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\x3C` is an escape sequence being interpreted as the `<` character, so you're actually doing this:

```
'<a href=#>Z<X</a>'
```

...which is invalid HTML, so the browser tries to make some sense of it, and what you're seeing is the result.

If you wanted that exact sequence of characters, you need to escape the backslash.

```
'<a href=#>Z\\x3CX</a>'
```